# Using PAW to test woo commerce api

Tags: paw-app

I'm trying to use PAW to connect to the WooCommerce API over http.  The documentation (https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/blob/master/source/includes/v2/_introduction.md)  mentions that you must use OAuth 1.0a "one-legged" authentication to ensure API credentials cannot be intercepted". And it also mentions that the required parameters are: oauth_consumer_key, oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, and oauth_signature_method. oauth_version is not required and must be omitted.

PAW's oauth1 always seems to includes PAW's oauth_version -- is there a way to to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. The `oauth_version` param is optional according to [the spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/), but servers should accept it, otherwise fall back on `1.0` if not present.

> oauth_version:
>   OPTIONAL. If present, value MUST be 1.0 . Service Providers MUST assume the protocol version to be 1.0 if this parameter is not present. Service Providers' response to non-1.0 value is left undefined.

http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

*As I think Paw should be more flexible than that, we will add an option to explicitly disable some parameters in a future version.*

Comment: Micha - is there a way I could accomplish something similar by creating my own dynamic value extension?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it's something you can easily do. I've made a start using an experiment we've done a while ago: https://gist.github.com/mittsh/9363584d50997c7c1a49 I haven't tested it, but it's the idea...